# Making Mario Party game but as soon as the game starts it declares a winner

Tags: c++

I'm making a mario party game with c++ for the sake of improving my coding skills. I want it to be pretty basic. It should be a two player game which allows each user to choose there character from an array. Then they'll roll dices and try and get stars. Its pretty much like a board game. The person to get a certain amount of stars which is chosen in the beginning of the game wins. The problem with my code is as soon as the first person rolls there dice it automatically gives them the hooray you win speech and asks if they want to play again.

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <cstdlib>
            #include <time.h>
            #include <conio.h>
            #include <windows.h>
            #include <string>

            using namespace std;

            void ChooseAmountofStars(int& Starnumbers)
            {
                //Gets the number of stars that will be in the game
                cout<<"How many stars do you want to search for, (1-3).\n";
                cin>>Starnumbers;
                cout<<"Great choice. The first player to retrieve "<<Starnumbers<<" Stars wins the game"<<endl;
            }


            int starplus(int Adder)
            {
                return Adder;
            }


            int PlaceStars()
            {
                //Place the star in a dice roll distance from the origin
                srand(time(0));
                int SpotNumber;
                SpotNumber=(rand()%50)+1;

                return SpotNumber;
            }


            int Winner(int Adder, int Starnumbers)
            {
                return starplus(Adder)==Starnumbers;
            }

            void coinplus(int& Adder)
            {
                int coin=0;
                coin+=20;
                if(coin>=100){
                    coin=0;
                    Adder+=1;
                    cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                }
            }

            int WhoGoesFirst(){

                srand(time(0));
                int chance;
                chance=(rand()%2)+1;
                if(chance == 1){
                    return 1;}
                else{
                        return 2;}

            }


            class Tools{
                public:

                    void MiniGame(){
                        rematch:
                        string Choices[3]={"Rock","Paper","Scissors"};
                        string UserChoice;

                        cout<<"Type your choice of either Rock, Paper, or Scissors"<<endl;
                        cin>>UserChoice;

                        int RandomNum=rand()%3;
                        srand(time(0));
                        string ComputerChoice;
                        ComputerChoice=Choices[RandomNum];

                        cout<<"Challenger chose: "<<ComputerChoice<<"\n";

                        if(UserChoice=="rock"){

                            if(ComputerChoice=="Rock"){
                                cout<<"It Is a Tie\n\n";
                                goto rematch;}

                            else if(ComputerChoice=="Paper"){
                                cout<<"Sorry, You Lose. Better Luck Next Time\n\n";}

                            else{
                                cout<<"Nice Job. You Win\n\n";}

                        }

                        else if(UserChoice=="paper"){

                            if(ComputerChoice=="Paper"){
                                cout<<"It Is a Tie\n\n";
                                goto rematch;}

                            else if(ComputerChoice=="Scissors"){
                                cout<<"Sorry, You Lose. Better Luck Next Time\n\n";}

                            else{
                                    cout<<"Nice Job. You Win\n\n";}

                        }

                        else if(UserChoice=="scissors"){

                            if(ComputerChoice=="Scissors"){
                                cout<<"It Is a Tie\n\n";
                                goto rematch;}

                            else if(ComputerChoice=="Rock"){
                                cout<<"Sorry, You Lose. Better Luck Next Time\n\n";}

                            else{
                                cout<<"Nice Job. You Win\n\n";}

                        }

                        else{
                            cout<<"Knock it off with the typos!!!\n\n";
                            goto rematch;
                        }
            }

                    void Dice(string player, int Adder)
                    {


                        int face=0;
                        int SpotNumber=PlaceStars();


                        system("cls");
                        cout << endl <<"--------------DICE---------------" << endl;
                        srand((unsigned)time(0));
                        cout << "Rolling..." << endl;
                        Sleep(2000);


                        face = (rand()%6)+1;

                        int spot=0;

                        if (face == 1)
                        {
                        cout << "     ___________" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         | " << endl;
                        cout << "     |    @    |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |_________|" << endl;
                        spot+=1;
                            if(spot>=50){
                                spot-=spot;
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                            else if(spot==9||spot==17||spot==32||spot==35||spot==47||spot==42||spot==25||spot==49){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                coinplus(Adder);
                            }
                            else if(spot==SpotNumber){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                Adder+=1;
                                cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                    cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                        }


                        else if (face == 2)
                        {
                        cout << "     ___________" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |       @ | " << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @       |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |_________|" << endl;
                        spot+=2;
                            if(spot>=50){
                                spot-=spot;
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                            else if(spot==9||spot==17||spot==32||spot==35||spot==47||spot==42||spot==25||spot==49){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                coinplus(Adder);
                            }
                            else if(spot==SpotNumber){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                Adder+=1;
                                cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                    cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                        }

                        else if (face == 3)
                        {
                        cout << "     ___________" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @       | " << endl;
                        cout << "     |    @    |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |       @ |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |_________|" << endl;
                        spot+=3;
                            if(spot>=50){
                                spot-=spot;
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                            else if(spot==9||spot==17||spot==32||spot==35||spot==47||spot==42||spot==25||spot==49){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                coinplus(Adder);
                            }
                            else if(spot==SpotNumber){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                Adder+=1;
                                cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                    cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                        }

                        else if (face == 4)
                        {
                        cout << "     ___________" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |_________|" << endl;
                        spot+=4;
                            if(spot>=50){
                                spot-=spot;
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                            else if(spot==9||spot==17||spot==32||spot==35||spot==47||spot==42||spot==25||spot==49){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                coinplus(Adder);
                            }
                            else if(spot==SpotNumber){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                Adder+=1;
                                cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                    cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                        }

                        else if (face == 5)
                        {
                        cout << "     ___________" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ | " << endl;
                        cout << "     |    @    |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |_________|" << endl;
                        spot+=5;
                            if(spot>=50){
                                spot-=spot;
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                            else if(spot==9||spot==17||spot==32||spot==35||spot==47||spot==42||spot==25||spot==49){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                coinplus(Adder);
                            }
                            else if(spot==SpotNumber){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                Adder+=1;
                                cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                    cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                        }

                        else if (face == 6)
                        {
                        cout << "     ___________" << endl;
                        cout << "     |         |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ | " << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ |" << endl;
                        cout << "     | @     @ |" << endl;
                        cout << "     |_________|" << endl;
                        spot+=6;
                            if(spot>=50){
                                spot-=spot;
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                            else if(spot==9||spot==17||spot==32||spot==35||spot==47||spot==42||spot==25||spot==49){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                coinplus(Adder);
                            }
                            else if(spot==SpotNumber){
                                cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                                Adder+=1;
                                cout<<"You have "<<starplus(Adder)<<" stars"<<endl;
                            }
                            else{
                                    cout<<player<<" landed on "<<spot<<endl;
                            }
                        }
            }



            };


            int main()
            {
                int Score1=0;
                //this will be used in parameter of dice for star count of plyr 1
                int Score2=0;
                //this will be used in parameter of dice for star count of plyr 2

                Tools ToolsObject;

                beginning:
                //If user would like to play again, they will start back at beginning

                cout<<"Plyr 1: Choose character from character list below\n";
                string ChaList[9]={"Mario ", "Luigi ","Peach ","Daisy ","Wario ","Waluigi ","Bowser ","Toad ","Yoshi"};
                for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
                    cout<<ChaList[i];
                }
                cout<<endl;
                //Displays player options for user1

                string Plyr1;
                cin>>Plyr1;
                cout<<"You chose "<<Plyr1<<endl;
                //Allows user to choose character and saves it in variable called Plyr1

                cout<<"Plyr 2: Choose character from character list below\n";
                for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
                    cout<<ChaList[i];
                }
                cout<<endl;
                //Displays player options for user2

                string Plyr2;
                cin>>Plyr2;
                cout<<"You chose "<<Plyr2<<endl;
                //Allows user to choose character and saves it in variable called Plyr2

                int StarNums=0;
                int StarNums2=0;

                ChooseAmountofStars(StarNums);
                //sets amount of stars to be found in order to win game. Parameter changes values the variable globally. it is set by reference.

                int position=PlaceStars();
                //Puts position of star from PlaceStars function into a variable that is local to main

                cout<<"The star is placed at spot: "<<position<<endl;

                int turn;
                turn = WhoGoesFirst();
                //Put the turn from WhoGoesFirst function into a variable that is local to main

                bool GameIsPlaying=true;
                while(GameIsPlaying==true){
                    if(turn==1){
                        ToolsObject.Dice(Plyr1, Score1);
                        if(Winner(Score1,StarNums)){
                            cout<<"Hurray you win"<<endl;
                            GameIsPlaying=false;
                            }

                        else{
                            turn=2;
                        }

                    }


                    else{
                        ToolsObject.Dice(Plyr2, Score2);
                        if(Winner(Score2,StarNums2)){
                            cout<<"Hurray you win"<<endl;
                            GameIsPlaying=false;}

                        else{
                            turn=1;
                        }

                    }
            }


                string desision;


                while(desision!="y" || desision!="n" ){
                    cout<<"Would you like to play again? (y or n)"<<endl;
                    cin>>desision;

                    if(desision=="y"){
                    cout<<"Get ready"<<endl;

                    goto beginning;
                    }

                    else if(desision=="n"){
                        cout<<"Enjoy the rest of the day"<<endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        cout<<"Not a valid choice"<<endl;
                    }
            }
            }
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of problems here, one of which is you are expecting this function

```
void Dice(string player, int Adder)
```

to alter the value of `Adder` that you pass to it here

```
ToolsObject.Dice(Plyr1, Score1);
```

This does not alter `Score1` as you are passing by value. If you want it to alter the argument, you should actually return a value or use reference or pointer argument.
As a consequence when your code reaches this line

```
if(Winner(Score1,StarNums)){
    cout<<"Hurray you win"<<endl;
    GameIsPlaying=false;
}
```

the `if` conditional is always satisfied because you are passing 2 variables to the `Winner` function which returns true when they are equal. As you have initialised them to zero and your other functions are not actually modifying you effectively have

```
if (0 == 0)
```

which is always true.

If you teach yourself to use a debugger properly, you will be able to identify such problems like this faster than the time it takes to post a question here.